# Where clause in LINQ method syntax

Tags: vb.net, linq

I'm having trouble determining where the 'Where' clause goes in the following LINQ query:

```
 Dim counts = eDTKBase.AsEnumerable(). _
                 GroupBy(Function(r) r.eDTK_PLI.). _
                 Select(Function(g) New With { _
                        .PLI_Code = g.Key, _
                        .CountPDP = g.Select(Function(r) r.eDTK_PDP_Code.). _
                        Distinct(). _
                        Count() _
```

I want the where clause to filter records where the count is >1. Can anyone help? Thanks.

Comment: Do you want to take the first record from the list? If so you can use `.First()`. If you want to filter by `r.count` you can do that using `Where()`?

Comment: No, I need to filter out all records where the count is > 1. I understand I need to use the Where clause, I just don't know where to place it or what the proper syntax is in this case.

Comment: Where the count *of what* is `> 1`?  Do you mean `.CountPDP`?  You're not being clear.

Comment: Sorry, yes where the count of .CountPDP > 1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
Dim counts = eDTKBase.AsEnumerable(). _
                 GroupBy(Function(r) r.eDTK_PLI.). _
                 Select(Function(g) New With { _
                        .PLI_Code = g.Key, _
                        .CountPDP = g.Select(Function(r) r.eDTK_PDP_Code.). _
                        Distinct(). _
                        Count() ...
                 }).Where(Function(w) w.CountPDP > 1)
```

To get the total count as asked in the comments

```
 Dim counts = eDTKBase.AsEnumerable(). _
                     GroupBy(Function(r) r.eDTK_PLI.). _
                     Select(Function(g) New With { _
                            .PLI_Code = g.Key, _
                            .CountPDP = g.Select(Function(r) r.eDTK_PDP_Code.). _
                            Distinct(). _
                            Count() ...
                     }).Where(Function(w) w.CountPDP > 1).Sum(Function(s) s.CountPDP)
```

Comment: Thanks Ceres but that didn't filter anything out, any other ideas?

Comment: Your incomplete code listing was a little confusing. I updated the answer.

Comment: Let me ask another question: how would I change the above to show just a count of the records returned in that query?